# Datetime cast string failing in Windows 7 but not in XP both SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

Why won't this string work in Windows 7, through VB.Net?

```sql
update [table] 
set [newlycreatedemptycolumn] = CAST(ENTRYEXPIREDATE + TEMPTIME as datetime)
```

- `entryexpiredate` is a `char` datatype, i.e. "2013-10-18"
- `temptime` is a `char` datatype, i.e. "23:59:00"

It works perfectly on my Windows XP machine, but not on Windows 7.

I am passing this query string through VB.Net. What am I missing?

```vbnet
strSQL = "update [table] set [dateTIMEcolumn] = CAST(ENTRYEXPIREDATE+TEMPTIME as datetime)"

Using connection As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
    command.Connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command.Connection.Close()
End Using
```

I receive this error message:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Is there a space between the date and time in one of those variables?  And do you mean that the SQL Server is on WinXP? Or the client application?  It would help to actually see the VB.NET code.  Is it even SQL Server or some other SQL RDBMS?

Comment: @MattJohnson 
here is the vb.net code, like i said when im at work developing on a windows xp machine. Now i am home on my Windows 7 and it will not create the column like it does when im at work.
`            strSQL = "update GymAssistant set entryexpiredateTIME = CAST(ENTRYEXPIREDATE+TEMPTIME as datetime)"
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(conStr)
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
                command.Connection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                command.Connection.Close()
            End Using`

Comment: What exactly does "failing" and "why won't it work" mean? You've provided no information about what the problem is you're experiencing. There's no definition of "failing", no explanation of "not working", and you're not asking a question that can be answered. What is the **problem** you want us to help you with here?

Comment: @KenWhite this is the error
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that information there where people can see it. Putting important details in comments is not helpful.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a space between the date and time values:

```
CAST(ENTRYEXPIREDATE + ' ' + TEMPTIME
```

Otherwise, if your date value is either VARCHAR or fills the defined CHAR length exactly, SQL server will see:

```
CAST('2013-10-1823:59:00' as datetime)
```

which is not a valid datetime.

Comment: Still didnt work, do i need to maybe trim because its in a char(40) column. Also i made a mistake the date is in the form of 11/1/13 if that changes anything

Comment: The char(40) column shouldn't matter as long as there is nothing else in there. Also, the date format shouldn't matter unless your system is using a non-US date format (although 11/1/13 should generally be ok).  Can you try just executing select CAST('11/1/13' + ' ' + '23:59:00' as datetime) against your DB server to see what happens. If it works, then the issue is most likely bad data in your database.

Comment: Thanks for you help  my original string above ended up working for me.  The problem as you stated was with my data.  there was a date that was 11/1/013.  which screwed everything up.  At home i am working on test DB where at work im working on actual backed up DB.  Here i am over thinking the code when its just a data issue. my apologies to everyone thanks for you help

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Thanks for the edit and the suggestion, but the code in the answer is SQL not VB. I have rolled back your edit.